# is it possible to call void as a string?

Tags: oop, vala

have been searching around for this but it's a little hard to describe so i'll just ask in here. Is it possible to call void as a string?

I think an example would describe it better:

```
//list of voids in the other class
string[] voids = {"expand()", "show()", "yolo()"};

anotherclass class = new anotherclass();

//call to the void named expand inside the other class
class.voids[0]; //??????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use string array, use function pointer array!

Two good links:

[link1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Function/Arrayoffunctionpointer.htm)
[link2](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#chapter2)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work even though vala support pointers. could you show an example using vala language?

Comment: It's called `delegate` in Vala: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Delegates